# Corte de control en java

Tags: java, poo, estructuras-de-datos

Es un algoritmo de corte de control tengo el archivo cargado en un vector ordnada por provincia. El problema es que al ingresar al bucle while mas interno cuando cambia el valor de linea este es igual a laa condicion del while pero no ingresa.

En el vector me queda cargado como muestra la imagen IZQ y luego del corte me tiene que quedar como la derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public static void corteDeControl(Sucursal []vecSucursal)
{
    int i = 0;
```

//cargar el registro de la posicion i en linea

```
    String linea = vecSucursal[i].generarRegistro();
    
    while(linea!=null)
    {
```

//cargo en aux la provincia de la posicion i

```
        String aux = vecSucursal[i].getProvincia();
```

//cuento la cantidad de suursales con el mismo nombre

```
        int contadorSucursal = 0;
```

// total provincia

```
        double acumuladorProvincia = 0.0;
        
        while(linea!=null && aux == vecSucursal[i].getProvincia())
        {
```

//cargo en aux1 el nombre sucural

```
            String aux1 = vecSucursal[i].getNombreSucursal();
```

//cantidad de impuesto de sucursal por provincia y nombre de sucursal

```
            int contadorImpuesto = 0;
```

//total sucursal por provincia y nombre sucursal

```
            double acumuladorSucursal = 0.0;
            
            while(linea!=null && aux == vecSucursal[i].getProvincia() && aux1 == vecSucursal[i].getNombreSucursal())
            {
                // total por sucursal de cada provincia

                acumuladorSucursal+=vecSucursal[i].getImporte();

                contadorImpuesto++;

                 //incremento indice del vector

               i++;
```

// actualizo linea ACA SALTA EL PROBLEMA NO ENTRA DE NUEVO Y DEBERIA DE ENTRAR

```
                linea = vecSucursal[i].generarRegistro();
            }
```

// total provincia

```
            acumuladorProvincia+=acumuladorSucursal;
            
            System.out.println("Provincia:" + vecSucursal[i].getProvincia());
            System.out.println("Cadena: " + vecSucursal[i].getNombreSucursal());
            System.out.println("Cantidad de impuestos: " + contadorImpuesto + " Importe: " + acumuladorSucursal);
          }
        System.out.println("Importe total: " + acumuladorProvincia + " provincia: " + vecSucursal[i].getProvincia());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

provinciaAnterior.compareTo(vecSucursal[i].getProvincia())==0

Solucionado al ser String comparo el String anterior con el actual y si es igual a cero me devuelve TRUE e ingresa al while